# Is it possible to modify list elements?

Tags: r, list

I have a list of records:

```
z <- list(list(a=1),list(a=4),list(a=2))
```

and I try to add fields to each of them.
Alas, neither

```
lapply(z,function(l) l$b <- 1+l$a)
```

nor

```
for(l in z) l$b <- 1+l$a
```

modifies `z`.

In this simple case I can, of course, do

```
z <- lapply(z,function(l) c(list(b= 1+l$a),l))
```

but this quickly gets out of hand when the lists have more nesting:

```
z <- list(list(a=list(b=1)),list(a=list(b=4)),list(a=list(b=2)))
```

How do I turn it into

```
list(list(a=list(b=1,c=2)),list(a=list(b=4,c=5)),list(a=list(b=2,c=3)))
```

without repeating the definition of the whole structure?
Each element of `z` has many fields, not just `a`; and `z[[10]]$a` has many subfields, not just `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code example doesn't modify the list because you need to return the list in your call to `lapply`:

```
z <- list(list(a=1),list(a=4),list(a=2))
expected <- list(list(a=1, b=2), list(a=4, b=5), list(a=2, b=3))
outcome <- lapply(z,function(l) {l$b <- 1+l$a ; l})
all.equal(expected, outcome)
# [1] TRUE
```

In the doubly nested example, you could use `lapply` within `lapply`, again making sure to return the list in the inner `lapply`:

```
z <- list(list(a=list(b=1)),list(a=list(b=4)),list(a=list(b=2)))
expected <- list(list(a=list(b=1, c=2)), list(a=list(b=4, c=5)), list(a=list(b=2, c=3)))
obtained <- lapply(z, function(l1) { lapply(l1, function(l2) {l2$c = l2$b+1 ; l2 } )})
all.equal(expected, obtained)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: actually, you do not need nested `lapply`; `lapply(z,function(l){l$a$c <- l$a$b+3; l})` works just fine!

Answer (score 2):

Another, somewhat convoluted, option:

```
z <- list(list(a=1),list(a=4),list(a=2))
res <- list(list(a=list(b=1,c=2)),list(a=list(b=4,c=5)),list(a=list(b=2,c=3)))
res1 <- rapply(z,function(x) list(b = x,c = x+1),how = "replace")
> all.equal(res,res1)
[1] TRUE
```

I only say convoluted because `rapply` can be tricky to use at times (for me at least).

Comment: Neat trick with `all.equal` to verify expected output -- it leads to much more concise responses!